# Springboot Jackson Generic data type serialize

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have a class

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {

    private T mObject;

    /**
     * @return the mObject
     */
    public T getmObject() {
        return mObject;
    }

    /**
     * @param mObject the mObject to set
     */
    public void setData(T mObject) {
        this.mObject = mObject;
    }
}
```

`T` is a generic type object which I set. So i'll initialize it like

`ResponseWrapper<Dog> responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
responseWrapper.setData(new Dog())`

In Dog class I have annotated it using `@JsonRootName("dog")`

My issue is, I want the JSON output should be like for ResponseWrapper

```
{
        "dog": {
                 "dogId": 19
               }
}
```

But my JSON is like

```
{
        "mObject": {
                 "dogId": 19
               }
}
```

It takes the name of the *variable name*. I expected jackson to take  @JsonRootName value instead of the variable name. But I guess I am missing something here.

Comment: Do you have `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE set  `?

Comment: I have this set spring.jackson.deserialization.unwrap-root-value=true.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@JsonPoperty`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) :

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    @JsonProperty("dog")
    private T mObject;

    /**
     * @return the mObject
     */
    public T getmObject() {
        return mObject;
    }

    /**
     * @param mObject the mObject to set
     */
    public void setData(T mObject) {
        this.mObject = mObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put @JsonProperty I'll get only "dog" as the root node.